# SvelteKit cookies disappearing upon site refresh, and returning the old value after an irrelevant API call

Tags: javascript, web, svelte, sveltekit

I am revamping my website using svelte(kit), but running into a very strange issue, whenever /api/signup/delivercode is called with a correct code, an account cookie is set, with no time expiry, when I refresh the page,  the cookie disappears, and then when I send a request to /api/signup after it disappeared, the OLD cookie reappears (at this point there isn't supposed to be any cookie yet (keep in mind it only appears when the signup api is called), only once the delivercode endpoint is triggered. Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong and why?

https://streamable.com/amc9t4
/api/signup endpoint:

```js
export const POST = async (event) => {
    // more code
    let response = await schemas.account.create(info).then(() => apiConsts.mail(event.cookies, info)) // I made sure with ctrl+f, this is the ONLY line where cookies are mentioned
    // more code
}
```

apiConsts.mail function:

```js
    mail: async (cookies, data, signup) => { // should move entire mail-code system to redis instead of mongo
        // more code
        cookies.set(`concode`, browserCode, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: `strict`, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30 }) // same here, this is the only place where the cookies object is mentioned
        // more code
    },
```

despite the fact that that those are the only locations where cookies are referenced in my code, the /api/signup sends an `account` cookie as well (see in first attached image), the cookie value is one that my code set beforehand (you can check the timeid, the first number in the start is the date in ms when it was created), it was just not visible in my browser nor with `event.cookies.get()` meanwhile, and it disappears again when I refresh (second attached video)

https://streamable.com/v6a27g
[image: receiving cookies]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a SvelteKit bug?

Comment: Do you have a `hooks.server.js` file? The cookie is probably set there.

Comment: I do not have any such file, the only files that should be interacting at the time where the cookies suddenly re-appear are the `/api/signup` endpoint and the `apiConsts.mail` function.

Comment: Provided info is not adequate to diagnose the problem. Don't just rely on devtools' cookie panel, you should also find the network request with the cookie setting/unsetting header. Also, use incognito mode or another browser to test if you can reproduce, so to make sure this problem is caused by sveltekit, cus it could also be caused by a browser extension.

Comment: @hackape the behaviour is identical in incognito, the first time it works okay, but as soon as the page redirects/refreshes the cookies disappear. The next time one is logging in, the old account cookie reappears before it's interacted with by my code.
(Also, note that I did check the requests that set the cookies, which you can see in my screenshot and my recordings)

Comment: I can’t see text clearly in the video. Anyway, I’m willing to help, but just don’t know how to proceed. Not enough info is all I said. Are you willing to share your codebase or what?

Comment: And since you did look into the request, what have you found unusual after hitting the reload button? The first response after reload must have some http headers that reset your cookies.

Comment: Oh! I checked the opposite of that, not where they were reset, oops! However I found the issue, will leave it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple: I had to pass the `path` key with a value of `/` in the settings object of the `cookies.set` function, this made it universal cookies that stick around no matter at what subpage you are located.